# save html5 canvas element to file using webos

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webos

here img variable is extracted from using Open Source Png Generation code here ..
http://www.xarg.org/2010/03/generate-client-side-png-files-using-javascript/  that is an alternative to canvas.toDataURL(); webOS does not support toDataURL so i had to use this lib.

here i have used this library and manipulated on my canvas image data pixel array

```
  EditorAssistant.prototype.getDataURL = function(width,height,data){   
     var p = new PNGlib(height, width, 256); // construcor takes height, weight and color-depth
 var background = p.color(0, 0, 0, 0); // set the background transparent

    for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
        var x = i * 10;
        var y = Math.sin(i) * Math.sin(i) * 50 + 50;
        // use a color triad of Microsofts million dollar color
          p.buffer[p.index(Math.floor(x), Math.floor(y))] = p.color(data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2]);
    }


return 'data:image/png;base64,'+p.getBase64() ;
}
```

honestly speaking i am newbie to node.js. i am just having an hit and trial APProach...
i want to save my manipulated canvas object to image directory in my application..
the path does exists here and this code does not generate any error .. rater it give me success on callback and also return number of bytes written but i cant find an image named icon.png in the images folder...
imgdata generated above is passed to this code as data..

```
  var fs = IMPORTS.require('fs');
var path = IMPORTS.require('path');


var buff = new Buffer(data,'binary').toString('base64'); 

 path.exists('images/', function(exists     ){
 if (exists) {

     fs.open('images/icon.png', 'w', 666, function( e, id ) {

          fs.write( id,  buff, null, 'binary', function(err,written){
            if(err)
                callback({
                    error: false,
                    reply: err
                });
            if(written){
                    callback({
                    error: false,
                    reply: buff.toString()
                });
            }   
            fs.close(id, function(){
                callback({
                    error: false,
                    reply: 'closed'
                });
            });
          });
        });

    }
    else {
        callback({
            error: true,
            reply: 'File did not exist.'
        });
    }
       }
   })
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I've not tried writing out files in webOS before, but are you sure you have permission to write where you're trying to?  You may not get an error, but webOS might fail silently when you try to write someplace you shouldn't, I don't know.

Comment: ok now it is working i have just changed the path to /media/internal/wallpapers/ ... it creates a png but it is empty .. now the question is...  how to load my canvas data to an image file is webOS?

Comment: has it something to do with right encoding ? how the png images shud be encoded ?

Answer (score 2):

`data` is a string which starts with `data:image/png;base64,` and the rest is the data in base64.

1. Remove `data:image/png;base64,` from `data`
2. Convert it from base64 to binary
3. Save that binary buffer to file

Code

```
var buff = new Buffer(data.substr('data:image/png;base64,'.length), 'base64');
...
fs.write(id, buff, 0, buff.length, 0, function(...
```

Comment: thnks mak ...i am now able to save image atleast

Comment: the code above works fine in the emulator but does not work for palm device