# node.js encoding images to save to file in webOS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [save html5 canvas element to file using webos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874521/save-html5-canvas-element-to-file-using-webos)

here img variable is extracted from using Open Source Png Generation code here ..

i have used this library and manipulated on my canvas image data pixel array

```
 EditorAssistant.prototype.getDataURL = function(width,height,data){   
 var p = new PNGlib(height, width, 256); // construcor takes height, weight and color-depth
 var background = p.color(0, 0, 0, 0); // set the background transparent

for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
    var x = i * 10;
    var y = Math.sin(i) * Math.sin(i) * 50 + 50;
    // use a color triad of Microsofts million dollar color
      p.buffer[p.index(Math.floor(x), Math.floor(y))] = p.color(data[i], data[i+1],  data[i+2]);
}

return 'data:image/png;base64,'+p.getBase64() ;
}
```

what are x and y here i dont know i just want to out my pixel array to this PNG

honestly speaking i am newbie to node.js. i am just having an hit and trial APProach... imgdata generated above is passed to this code as data..
there are two issues with the code
1: it creates a file with size equal to number of bytes written to the file,but it is empty i am sure it is some encoding issue...
2:this code does not save the actual canvas pixel array in the file it creates...

```
var fs = IMPORTS.require('fs');
var path = IMPORTS.require('path');


var buff = new Buffer(data,'binary').toString('base64');

path.exists('images/', function(exists     ){
 if (exists) {

   fs.open('images/icon.png', 'w', 666, function( e, id ) {

      fs.write( id,  buff, null, 'binary', function(err,written){
        if(err)
            callback({
                error: false,
                reply: err
            });
        if(written){
                callback({
                error: false,
                reply: buff.toString()
            });
        }   
        fs.close(id, function(){
            callback({
                error: false,
                reply: 'closed'
            });
        });
      });
    });

}
else {
    callback({
        error: true,
        reply: 'File did not exist.'
    });
 }
   }
})
```

help me plz
thnks